# spark snowflake connector sql query SQL compilation error

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, jvm, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to query snowflake using input variable from my function (run via aws glue).. Below are 3 things I've tried but I keep getting the following error:

*An error occurred while calling o14310.load. SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 94*

Any ideas what the issue may be?  Regular queries not using an input variable runs fine..

```
def s_counts(df, s_id):
what_to_query = "select R_ID FROM mytable WHERE S_ID ="+s_id
CurrentCount = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
   .options(**sfOptions)
   .option("query", what_to_query)
   .load()

CurrentCount = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
   .options(**sfOptions)
   .option("query", "select R_ID FROM mytable WHERE S_ID = s_id")
   .load()

CurrentCount = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
   .options(**sfOptions)
   .option("query", "select R_ID FROM mytable WHERE S_ID = "+s_id)
   .load()
```

Comment: there is a very high chance that the input variable `s_id` is not passed properly, and you ended up with an incomplete query `select R_ID FROM mytable WHERE S_ID =`

Comment: Should the `S_ID` in your where clause be `R_ID` i.e. `select R_ID FROM mytable WHERE R_ID = `  instead of `select R_ID FROM mytable WHERE S_ID=` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping `s_id` in quotes. For example

```py
what_to_query = "select R_ID FROM mytable WHERE S_ID = '{0}'".format(s_id)
```

or

```py
what_to_query = "select R_ID FROM mytable WHERE S_ID = '%s'" % (s_id)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks ggordon! The second one worked for me!

Comment: @pdangelo4 Great! Please mark this answer as the accepted answer so that other stackoverflow users with similar questions will be able to identify suitable answers to their questions.